# Gradle cannot compile .aar file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to add an external library. I've created in a/libs folder under project folder and have the following code in my gradle.build file. But it doesn't sync at all.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }  
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.radiusnetworks:AndroidIBeaconLibrary:0.7.1@aar'
}
```

The error I'm getting is:
Gradle 'BLE_Client' project refresh failed:
            Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'compile()'!
            Possible causes could be:
            - you are using Gradle version where the method is absent 
            - you didn't apply Gradle plugin which provides the method
            - or there is a mistake in a build script

Comment: This looks like it's the root, ````build.gradle```` file based off the file comments... Shouldn't the ````dependencies```` macro be under the ````buildscript```` or ````allprojects```` closure?

Comment: I've tried both of that - adding inside allProjects and dependencies macro inside buildscript. It still gives an error:


No signature of method:org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.compile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [com.radiusnetworks:AndroidIBeaconLibrary:0.7.1@aar]
           Possible solutions: module(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Next guess is that the root build.gradle file knows nothing of android and AARs, apply it to the application build.gradle file when the android-plugin is a known thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't add this dependency to the root-level **build.gradle** file. Add it to your module's **build.gradle** file instead. The top-level build file is for things that are common to all modules in your project, but it's highly unlikely that you'd want all modules to have the same dependencies, or even to share this one.

Comment: @Scott How  to represent local files in lower level build.gradle

Comment: The easiest thing is to just use the UI in the Project Structure dialog. It will do the right thing.